# R : H2O initialization issue on local host ( Error in .h2o.startJar : Return Code = 1)

Tags: r, h2o

I am getting the following error by running this code:

```
h2o.init()
```

> H2O is not running yet, starting it now...
>   Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
>   C:\Users\312406\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEbcklD/h2o_312406_started_from_r.out
>   C:\Users\312406\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEbcklD/h2o_312406_started_from_r.err
>
> java version "1.8.0_161"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
>
> Error in .h2o.startJar(ip = ip, port = port, nthreads = nthreads, max_memory = max_mem_size,  :
>     Failed to exec "C:/R/R-3.4.2/library/h2o/java/h2o.jar" with return code=1
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   running command '"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe" -Dsys.ai.h2o.debug.allowJavaVersions=11 -ea -cp "C:/R/R-3.4.2/library/h2o/java/h2o.jar" water.H2OApp -name H2O_started_from_R_312406_dgc000 -ip localhost -web_ip localhost -port 54321 -ice_root C:/Users/312406/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpEbcklD' had status 1
>
> H2o Version : 3.20.0.8
>   R : R-3.4.2
>   R Studio : Version 1.1.419
>   OS : WINDOWS 10 Enterprise
>   Version : 1083
>   OS Build : 17143.1
>   arch : x86_64

Comment: Could you explain more about the issue you are having?

Comment: You have two options:  look at the stdout and stderr files, or try to run that command yourself by hand on the command line and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This general question comes up a lot for various reason, as recommended in the comments you should look at the `stdout` and `stderr` files (which are listed in your error message), or try to run the command to launch your h2o.jar yourself on the command line and see what happens - documentation help is [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/starting-h2o.html#from-the-command-line).

I would also look at the [trouble shooting](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/faq/general-troubleshooting.html?highlight=windows) in the user guide or search on [h2ostream](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/h2ostream/h2o.init()$20windows%7Csort:date) for your error.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting the sdtout & stderr did not show any error. The issue got resolved , it was due to Antivirus and Firewall restrictions to connect to local host.